# Jquery to Pure Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to convert this small `script` to a pure `vanilla JS`.

```
$('input, textarea').focus(function() { 
        $(this).data('placeholder', $(this).attr('placeholder')).attr('placeholder', '');
    }).blur(function() { 
            $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).data('placeholder'));
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/axmh1zac/)

Thanks to Treast, I'm here at this point... Almost working good:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea');

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    element.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        element.setAttribute('data-placeholder', element.getAttribute('placeholder'));
        element.setAttribute('placeholder', '');
    }),
  element.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        element.setAttribute('placeholder', element.getAttribute('data-placeholder'));
        element.setAttribute('data-placeholder', '');
    });
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/axmh1zac/1/)

Any idea please?

Comment: You miss an “e” in `Attribute`.

Comment: Also `element.addEventListener("blur"...`

Comment: Is this for some older browser or something? There shouldn't be a need to add / remove the `placeholder` attribute on focus/blur on modern browsers that properly support `placeholder`

Comment: No, actually that's only for visual comfort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('input, textarea')` will select ALL input or textarea. With Vanilla, you cannot add an `EventListener` on a list of elements, so you need to loop through all elements. And you need to use `querySelectorAll` to get the same list. Also, you cannot chain `addEventListener`.

So your code will be:

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea');

```
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    element.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        this.setAttribute('data-placeholder', this.getAttribute('placeholder'));
        this.setAttribute('placeholder', '');
    });
    element.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        this.setAttribute('placeholder', this.getAttribute('data-placeholder'));
        this.setAttribute('data-placeholder', '');
    });
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks!
It works well for only textarea... Bug on input!

Comment: Sorry, it's fixed. I was using a bad reference to the element. Now works well :)

Comment: THANK YOU buddy!

Answer (score 1):

Have a good look at [Patrick's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50077035/jquery-to-pure-vanilla-js/50077484#comment87170975_50077035) above about if this is even needed.

--

As for converting your code to vanilla JS, I think the only issue with your **Demo 2** is an unclosed Button tag. I'd suggest splitting things up to help readability. Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/Lebxdrwk/2/

```
const onFocus = event => {
  const element = event.target;
  const placeholder = element.getAttribute('placeholder');
  element.setAttribute('data-placeholder', placeholder);
  element.setAttribute('placeholder', '');
};

const onBlur = event => {
  const element = event.target;
  const dataPlaceholder = element.getAttribute('data-placeholder');
  element.setAttribute('placeholder', dataPlaceholder);
  element.setAttribute('data-placeholder', '');
}

const addEventListenersToSwapPlaceholders = element => {
  element.addEventListener('focus', onFocus);
  element.addEventListener('blur', onBlur);
}

document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea')
  .forEach(addEventListenersToSwapPlaceholders);
```

Comment: Your script looks right, l don't see where it missed something... Your script remove the placeholder on focus but doesn't restore it on blur...

Comment: Yep, there's a copy/paste error in there. The onBlur method is reading from "placeholder" instead of "data-placeholder". Sorry, I've edited the answer.